# Configuration for windows authentication via IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to configure windows authentication for my asp.net application via IIS 7.0.

I notice that when i try to login using the AD user accounts. I can only login through windows authentication mode for my application if the AD user is added to IIS_IUSRS or Administrator group. Why is this so? Is that any configuration that i need to make or is it true that for every user account that need to login to the asp.net application via windows authentication in IIS 7.0 needed to be added to these few groups?

Kindly advise thanks